# Which type of authentication in a jhipster app should I use if I wanted to connect with spring rest shell?

Tags: java, jhipster, spring-rest

we will be using JHipster to scaffold a spring boot app. Which authentication type should I choose if I wanted to connect with [Spring Rest Shell](https://github.com/spring-projects/rest-shell) to the REST API generated by jhipster?

Answer (score 0):

This is opinion only, but I would use Token authentication. I just did a Mule connector to my JHipster app and I like that I can check for the existence of a token (== null) and if null, api/authenticate. After I have the token, I just add the header with each REST request.

Answer (score 0):

Token-based approach would be best fit if you don't need OAuth in your application.